# jQuery AJAX load content with fadeIn

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, load, fadein

I have a container in where content should load from different php files. 
So I have this:

```
$('ul#menu li a').click(function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#wind').load('pages/'+ page +'.php');
    return false;
});
```

the page content loads into the div and everything looks nice but it appears instantly and just looks wrong, is there a way to append `fadeIn()` somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have the div `#wind` hidden at first then within the callback function of `.load()` fade it in.

```
$('#wind').load('pages/' + page + '.php', function () {
    $('#wind').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

yes. you can use jquery .load function for loading your data with fadIn().

`$("#container").fadeOut("slow").load('data.php').fadeIn('slow');`